# realloc(): invalid next size. Fail to read the http page into string

Tags: c, memory, malloc, realloc

I am trying to read from the HTTP page and save the whole page as a string.
While realloc() the memory, the error occurs, stating that: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001505e10 ***...

Below is my code, thanks in advance

```
char* get_http(int my_socket, char* buffer){
    char* http_page = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    assert(http_page);
    int cur_size = BUFFER_SIZE;
    int cur_len = 0;

    // read the http, and write into http_page

    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    while (read(my_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1) != 0){
        // if the size if not enough, reallocate the memory
        if (cur_len + strlen(buffer) >= cur_size){
            cur_size = cur_size* 2;
            http_page = (char*)realloc(http_page, cur_size);
            assert(http_page);
        }
        cur_len += strlen(buffer);
        strcpy(http_page + cur_len, buffer);
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    }
    return http_page;}
```

Comment: Why not `while (cur_len + strlen(buffer) >= cur_size){ ...` That way you are covered if `cur_size* 2;` is less than `cur_len + strlen(buffer)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```cpp
cur_len += strlen(buffer);
strcpy(http_page + cur_len, buffer);
```

You update the `cur_len` before you make a copy, so the copied data go to a wrong address resulting in broken heap.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at realloc for a long time and could not realise where I did wrong.